# How can I create a path with the brush tool in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, graphics-editing

I know how to stroke a path (even with the brush tool). That is not the issue. My question is how can I create a path with something continuous instead of having to click to create a new support point along the path?

The sampling frequency might be time- or distance-from-last-based. Or even something else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way - 
However, you might just paint what you want as path with any painting tool in the quick mask enabled (click on the button to the left of the horizontal scroll bar to toggle the quick mask) - on toggling the quick mask off, what you painted there is your selection - then you can convert your selection to a path. `Select->To Path`.

It will create a closed path, instead of a single line like I suppose you want, but it is the only possible way with GIMP.

You might otherwise use Inkscape, which is a vector based tool, with lots of other options available for its paths, and that allows free-hand path drawing.